# Probability tree in SPSS/ R/ others?

Tags: bigdata, r, python

Similar questions have been asked in this context but this one seems a bit different.

**[Aim]**
We would like to find out what the probability is of a person purchasing a 4USD column D (see below) price given that he has purchased C-2, B-2, A

[image]

**[Context]**
We have a sizeable dataset of about 500,000 observations of this pattern. E.g. customer decides to buy A), bought B-1, then C-2, D-3.

**[Issue]**
We don't know how deep the events reach. E.g. it can be to column E, F, G. That's why we would like to auto-generate a probability tree in preferably SPSS but are open to other solutions as well.
How does this look like mathmatically? Can we just extend bayes conditional probability? If so, how does it look? Any potential issues?
Any other comments/ ideas are always welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want to do a market basket analysis. But maybe I understand your question incorrectly. If you are interested in market basket analysis try [arules package](http://lyle.smu.edu/IDA/arules/).

Comment: In SAS proc dtree is for this exact problem.

Comment: In R you can use `library(rpart)` for this task.